# resource to combine external and internal javascript files into as few as possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, filesize

I'm looking for a solution to combine several javascript files into as few as possible. I currently have many files from external sources like twitter, facebook, google+ etc.. as well as few of my own.

Is it possible to somehow automatically combine this into one, or as few as possible files?

If not all of them than combine external and internal files separately.

Comment: Have you tried just putting them all in one big js file and linking that in your page?

Comment: I'd suggest you to only combine all your own files to a single one, minify it and keep other external files (twitter, etc...) alone to keep advantage of caching as your clients could already have these files in their browser cache.

Comment: You will run into CORS issues if you compile external files and host them from your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If downloading the external files and placing them in your server is an option, the you can use a tool like:

- [Gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/)
- [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets)
- [Apache ant](http://ant.apache.org/)
- [RequireJs Optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html)

To compile the js (and usually minify it) into one big file.

That being said I recommend that you keep the external files in the external cdn you load them, because they probably cache them and it'll be faster.

Keep in mind that having only one file isn't always the best way to go (it depends on things like size of the resulting file, if you really have to load it, etc).